# How to use i18n in a config file in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization

I created a config file for pagination settings .. (application/config/paginaton.php)

and im using i18n in that project, i've tried to use

```
$config['last_link'] = $this->lang->line('pagination_last_link);
```

and a lang file (application/language/english/pagination_lang.php)

```
$lang['pagination_first_link'] = 'First';
$lang['pagination_last_link']  = 'Last';
```

but it doesn't work...

i'm also using autoload

```
$autoload['language'] = array('pagination');
```

-- error message:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$lang

Filename: config/pagination.php

Line Number: 15

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your config file is a simple php file containing an array; it doesn't have access to the CI superobject, so the moment you do

```
$this->lang->line('pagination_last_link')
```

You're trying am invalid access

I don't know if this might work but try using:

```
$CI = &get_instance();

$config['last_link'] = $CI->lang->line('pagintion_last_ling');
```

in your `application/config/paginaton.php`